# How can i take all array elements when i don't know array size in c/c++?

Tags: c++

I want to take input like `20, 30, 10, 40..`so on. And I want to do operations on them. Note that there have no terminal character or number.

```
int i = 0;
while (scanf("%d", &arr[i]) == 1)
    i++;
```

Above code can be use but it is an infinite loop!!

Comment: There is no such language c/c++. Make your mind.

Comment: C or C++?.........

Comment: And an infinitite look like such would require an infinite array, and that's not realistic.

Comment: Very different languages means very different solutions.

Comment: Which language, C or C++ (very important here)?  For example in C, you have to dynamically allocate an array.  In C++ you have `std::vector` which handles the memory allocation and deallocation for you.

Comment: Please implement in c++

Answer (score 2):

Since you tagged your answer as C++, here is the common idiom:

```
int i = 0;
std::vector<int> numbers;
while (std::cin >> i)
{
  numbers.push_back(i);
}
```

The loop takes input from the *standard input* stream and places into a `vector`.  The input is terminated either by end of data or there was an error reading an integer (such as alphabetic text).  The "end of data" is platform specific, for example, on some Windows platform you can use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd> other platforms you can use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd>.

**Edit 1: Arrays**
If you must use an array, you may have to change the size:

```
size_t  capacity = 4;
int * p_array = new int [capacity];
int value = 0;
size_t quantity = 0;
while (std::cin >> value)
{
  if (quantity >= capacity)
  {
    capacity *= 2;
    int * p_larger_array = new int[capacity];
    std::copy(p_array, p_array + quantity, p_larger_array);
    delete [] p_array;
    p_array = p_larger_array;
  }
  p_array[quantity] = value;
}
```

Comment: I don't think this answers the question.

Comment: I think it does. Might want to expand a bit on what the terminating condition is, though.

Comment: @Quentin: The OP didn't specify what the terminating condition is for the input.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews in your code, I mean -- it's in the documentation of `std::basic_ios::operator bool`, but wouldn't hurt to sum up here :)

Comment: Bro here is the problem is have no terminal input :(

Comment: @TarikulIslam you probably have *some* terminating condition on your input. Otherwise, just enter a `while`/`sleep` loop and wait until the heat death of the universe.

Comment: @TarikulIslam please tell us why this answer doesn't work for you. Did you try it?

Comment: @Quentin: Added text about terminating condition.

Comment: @TarikulIslam It works fine [__here__](https://www.ideone.com/Topwly)